# Is there any way to cache request with auth headers in varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Is there any way to cache request with auth headers in varnish?
I want to ignore the auth headers while caching the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to approach this, depending on the importance of auth headers.

### 1. You don't care about auth

If you don't care about the auth part and if you want to risk serving cached content to unauthorized users, you can just use the following VCL code:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.Authorization;
}
```

### 2. Ignore authorization to some extent

It is also possible to care about auth a bit, but not too much.

The following VCL snippet will allow caching even if there is an `Authorization` header:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.http.Authorization) {
        return(hash);
    }
}
```

The consequence of this is that the initial cache miss will pass through to the backend and will be processed there. Potential unauthorized access will be handled there.

But as soon as the has been dealt with, the object is stored in the cache and the next requests will get cached content regardless of the authorization status of that request.

### 3. Perform auth on the edge

It is also possible to handle the auth part in Varnish while caching the content.

The following VCL code will handle this:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.http.Authorization != "Basic YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0") {
        return (synth(401, "Restricted"));
    }
    unset req.http.Authorization; 
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 401) {
        set resp.http.WWW-Authenticate = {"Basic realm="Restricted area""};
    }
}
```

This code will actively inspect the content of the `Authorization` header and will ensure the username `admin` is used with password `secret`.

The `YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0` string is nothing more than a base64 encoding of `admin:secret`.

### 4. Use vmod_basicauth

A more advanced and flexible way to terminate auth on the edge is by using https://git.gnu.org.ua/vmod-basicauth.git/. This VMOD can be compiled from source and can be downloaded from ftp://download.gnu.org.ua/release/vmod-basicauth.

Assuming the credentials are stored in `/var/www/.htpasswd`, you can leverage this VMOD to match the `Authorization` header to the content of the `.htpasswd` file.

Here's the VCL:

```
vcl 4.1;

import basicauth;

sub vcl_recv {
    if (!basicauth.match("/var/www/.htpasswd",req.http.Authorization)) {
        return (synth(401, "Restricted"));
    }
    unset req.http.Authorization;
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 401) {
        set resp.http.WWW-Authenticate = {"Basic realm="Restricted area""};
    }
}
```

Comment: Not applicable for authorization headers, but for api key headers can the `Vary` header from the server also be help?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible but also extremely dangerous: Varnish would return the same cached (authorized) content to all requests.

Example:

User A requests resource Z with proper authentication. Varnish relays the request to backend, caches the response and returns the resource.

User B requests resource Z with proper authentication. They will get the cached resource Z **even if Z contains user A's content**.

User X requests resource Z with **invalid authentication**. They will too get the cached resource anyway since the backend is bypassed.

---

Having said that, you can override Varnish's built-in VCL. Details are [documented](https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/) but the main idea is:

Copy default `vcl_recv` VCL (for your version) from [source](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl) and add it to the end of your `vcl_recv`.

Remove the safeguards from `vcl_recv`: Just remove `vcl_req_authorization` which disables caching:

```
sub vcl_req_authorization {
    if (req.http.Authorization) {
        # Not cacheable by default.
        return (pass);
    }
}
```

In your `vcl` file issue a `return` statement at the end so built-in `vcl` is not used.